# Expose CSRF tokens to the client-side

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a web application that consists of two parts:

1. `app-front` React application, that deployed in AWS CloudFront, and avaliable via app-example.com
2. `app-api` Node.js + Koa application, that deployed in EC2 instance (behind load balancer), and avaliable via api.app-example.com

`app-api` has CSRF protection, that uses a secret key in user session and token that is verified on the server side. (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_Token_Pattern)

How can `app-api` expose CSRF tokens to the `app-front` ?

There are several ways:

1. Include the token in html pages:

   `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrfToken}}">`

But this method does not work for me, because `app-api` doesn't serve html pages (`app-front` located in AWS CloudFront)

2. Set CSRF tokens in cookies via AJAX

   `server.get('/csrf', (req, res) => {
       res.cookie('_csrf' , res.locals._csrf, {expire : new Date() + 9999});
       return res.json({
           "status": "success"
       })
   })`

But this is an additional request that I would like to avoid.

Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: can we use sessionStorage or localStorage at client side to store csrf tokens

Comment: @TanmayPatil but how can I transfer the token from the server to the client in the best way?

Comment: One option i can think is to use middleware like csrf . reference : https://github.com/koajs/csrf